# Expose functions inside Vuex Plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to expose `undo` function inside Vuex plugin, to use in my component for click events.

```
// plugin.js
  const timeTravel = store => {
  // .. other things
  function undo () {
    store.commit('commit_something', payload)
  }
}
```

How do I expose `undo` function to components so I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Vuex plugins do not expose anything outside their context. They are made to hook into mutations while receiving the store object. Your `undo` function would be better suited as an action within a store/module(s).

If you have several modules that need to make use of `undo`, look at the section [Module Reuse](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#module-reuse).